# Custom font not working on selective target on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts

I tried to use a custom font(Gilroy-Regular) in my app. My app has 3 targets, newly added custom font works fine for 2 targets/apps but it's not working with only one target.

1. Have checked the Info.plist file
2. Have checked the Target of .ttf file
3. Checked whether the font file is there Copy Bundle resources

But the font change is not applied.  I tried with below code but its not printing the custom font.

```
 for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]){
      NSLog(@"Family name: %@", familyName);
      for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
           NSLog(@"--Font name: %@", fontName);
      }
  }
```

Have tried with many solutions provided on stack overflow but it doesn't works yet.

Comment: I assume you've `Product -> Clean Build Folder`? Double (and triple) checked spelling in `.plist`? Maybe try creating a 4th target... see if the font shows up... If so, try to figure out what was different.

Comment: Yup have tried clean build folder, this is the file name which I included Gilroy-Regular.ttf

Comment: Are all the apps for the same platform?

Comment: @HalR yes it is